# Grouping 30 distinct objects into 6 bags, each containing 5 objects such that 2 go in the same bag

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I treated the 2 objects as 1 and then grouped them, is this correct?

My try:
$$\frac{29!}{5!^5\times 4!\times 5!}$$

Comment: If you are assuming that the bags are indistinguishable, that should be stated explicitly in the problem.

Comment: I agree with the comment of @N.F.Taussig.  Also, if you are assuming the opposite, that the bags are distinguishable, then that should be explicitly stated.  Please edit your question to clarify your assumption.  In the meantime, since I have already given an answer based on one assumption, I wll add an Addendum to address the other assumption.

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes that the $6$ bags are distinguishable from each other.

---

Ignoring the constraint re two specific items in the same bag, there are

$$\binom{30}{5} \times \binom{25}{5} \times \binom{20}{5} \times \binom{15}{5} \times \binom{10}{5}\tag1$$

different distributions possible.  (1) above simplifies to

$$T = \frac{30!}{[5!]^6}.\tag2$$

To impose the constraint, assuming Without Loss of Generality that item-1 went into bag-1, there are then $29$ different (and equally likely) places that item-2 might have gone, of which only $4$ of the $29$ are satisfactory.

Therefore, the final enumeration is:

$$\frac{4}{29} \times T = \frac{4}{29} \times \frac{30!}{[5!]^6}.$$

---

**Addendum**
Responding to the comment of N. F. Taussig, that the OP (i.e. original poster) may have intended that the bags are indistinguishable.

Since my original answer assumes that the bags are distinguishable, the easiest approach is to now assume that the bags are indistinguishable, and analyze how that affects the answer.

First, temporarily ignore the constraint re two specific items in the same bag.

Labeling the objects as $O_1$ through $O_{30}$,
consider the following distribution:

Bag-1 : $O_1$ through $O_5$.
Bag-2 : $O_6$ through $O_{10}$.
Bag-3 : $O_{11}$ through $O_{15}$.
Bag-4 : $O_{16}$ through $O_{20}$.
Bag-5 : $O_{21}$ through $O_{25}$.
Bag-6 : $O_{26}$ through $O_{30}$.

If you assume that the bags are indistinguishable, then the above distribution would be the same as (for example), the following distribution:

Bag-2 : $O_1$ through $O_5$.
Bag-3 : $O_6$ through $O_{10}$.
Bag-4 : $O_{11}$ through $O_{15}$.
Bag-5 : $O_{16}$ through $O_{20}$.
Bag-6 : $O_{21}$ through $O_{25}$.
Bag-1 : $O_{26}$ through $O_{30}$.

In fact, there are $(6!)$ different distributions that are now considered identical.  That is, there are $(6)$ choices for the bag assigned to objects $O_1$ through $O_5$, and then $(5)$ choices for the bag assigned to objects $O_6$ through $O_{10}$, and so forth.

Furthermore, for any distribution of :

Bag-1 : Any $(5)$ items 
Bag-2 : Any $(5)$ of the remaining $(25)$ items 
Bag-3 : Any $(5)$ of the remaining $(20)$ items 
Bag-4 : Any $(5)$ of the remaining $(15)$ items 
Bag-5 : Any $(5)$ of the remaining $(10)$ items 
Bag-6 : The last $(5)$ items

The same analysis pertains.  That is, if you assume that the bags are indistinguishable, then there are $(6!)$ ways that the $(6)$ bags can be permuted in their assignment of the objects, without altering the distribution.

This means that there is a general *over-counting* factor of $(6!)$ that has to be applied, if you assume that the bags are indistinguishable.

This implies that absent the constraint that two items must be in the same bag, the enumeration of distinct distributions is now

$$S = \frac{30!}{[5!]^6 \times 6!}.$$

Now, applying the constraint that two items must be in the same bag, the factor of $\displaystyle \frac{4}{29}$ that was inferred in the original analysis is unaffected by whether the bags are considered indistinguishable.

This implies that the final enumeration is now

$$\frac{4}{29} \times S = \frac{4}{29} \times \frac{30!}{[5!]^6 \times (6!)}.$$

Comment: The factor of $5!$ in the denominator of alter's attempt suggests that alter assumed the bags were indistinguishable.  I suggest seeking clarification.  Of course, your answer is correct under the assumption that the bags are distinct.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig See my Addendum.

Comment: I see that alter has not (yet) responded.  For the case in which the bags are indistinguishable, the bag which contains the two particular objects of concern is distinguished from the others because it contains those objects.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Agreed, which is what I tried to express in my Addendum.  Is there an analytical mistake in my Addendum?

Comment: After checking that your method works for small cases, I concluded that your answers for both conditions are correct.